# How do I type the slanted apostrophe on the command line?

Tags: command-line, character, apostrophe

I'm running a React Native app on an iPhone from the command line, and use the command `react-native run-ios --device "<my name>’s iPhone"`. The problem is I always have to copy-paste this, because the apostrophe in `<my name>’s` is different from the apostrophe when I actually type `<my name>'s`. `’` vs `'`. How do I type `’`?

Comment: That character is not ASCII. There is no *curved apostropy* character in ASCII.

Comment: Understood. The problem is I can't run the command without it. Any idea how?

Comment: From a command prompt? No. Why are you using that symbol in your phone name instead of a plain apostrophe (which would solve the entire problem you're having)?

Comment: I don't control the phone name. React Native recognizes whichever devices are plugged in, and in order to run it on that device from the command line, to my knowledge the only way is to add your phone's name, which in my case includes that particular apostrophe. If I use the regular ASCII apostrophe it says it doesn't recognize the name.

Comment: Whether the chracter is ASCII or not is completely irrelevant, and Apple automatically names iPhones with this type of apostrophe.  It's a completely valid use case. Why comment when you have nothing useful to contribute? @KenWhite

Answer (score 0):

On windows you would type alt+0146 and on mac  option+shift+] . It's a unicode character so, like all other special unicode characters, it depends on your setup for how you can type it without copy-pasting.

If you don't want to memorize the shorcuts you can also keep in mind most word processors will automatically sub ASCII apostrophes for curves unicode ones, and then you will still be copy-pasting but without the five minutes of google searching.

I don't have enough points to comment but Ken White's assertion that you're at fault for naming your phone with the curved apostrophe seems unreasonable. This is the default way Apple products name devices.